# groupby after concat, column missing in the group mean

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

concat two dataframe, then groupby 'type' and calculate the mean, columns of second df, i.e. d1~d10, showing in the concat'ed dataframe but not in the grouped mean. i might have missed some pt... pls indicate... here the codes.

```
results=pd.concat([stockpicks,stock_analysis],axis=1)
print(stockpicks.head(5))
print(stock_analysis.head(5))
print(results.head(5))


results_typed=results.groupby('type')
mean_overall=results_typed.mean()

print(mean_overall)
```

here below the output.

```
         date  type stocknum  price      pe
0  2014-02-17  cao3  0326.HK   0.20   20.00
1  2014-02-17  cao3  0536.HK   2.56   25.60
2  2014-02-17  cao3  0595.HK   0.97   48.50
3  2014-02-17  cao3  0698.HK   0.95   15.83
4  2014-02-17  cao3  0759.HK   3.25  108.33

[5 rows x 5 columns]
         d1        d2        d5       d10
0        95        95        95        90
1  99.21875       100  97.65625   89.0625
2       100  107.2165  104.1237  93.81443
3  102.1053  97.89474  97.89474  105.2632
4  95.38462  94.15385        92  90.15385

[5 rows x 4 columns]
         date  type stocknum  price      pe        d1        d2        d5  \
0  2014-02-17  cao3  0326.HK   0.20   20.00        95        95        95   
1  2014-02-17  cao3  0536.HK   2.56   25.60  99.21875       100  97.65625   
2  2014-02-17  cao3  0595.HK   0.97   48.50       100  107.2165  104.1237   
3  2014-02-17  cao3  0698.HK   0.95   15.83  102.1053  97.89474  97.89474   
4  2014-02-17  cao3  0759.HK   3.25  108.33  95.38462  94.15385        92   

        d10  
0        90  
1   89.0625  
2  93.81443  
3  105.2632  
4  90.15385  

[5 rows x 9 columns]
          price         pe
type                      
bbom   2.050526   8.135789
bbos   3.136842  10.116316
cao3   1.717368  36.494211
maos   6.661935  20.565161
rscp  48.983333   6.280000

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

actually i have been rewriting the codes. before i expanded the first df by reindexing, and then assign the values to the expanded df, groupby 'type' and calculated the grouped mean, no problem at all...

i am using python3.3 with pandas 13.1 on ubuntu.

the statement to calculate d values

```
days=[1,2,5,10]
p0=stockprice[p0_date]
stock_pct_change={('d'+str(d)):stockprice[p0_date+d]/p0*100.0 if (p0_date+d)< len(trading_days) else np.nan for d in days }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The missing columns are because they are strings/dates/objects and computing the mean is meaningless for these columns.

It looks to me like your columns d1, d2, d5 and d10 are strings as the output is showing them as a mixture of ints/floats.

If you want to compute the means of these columns then change their dtype like so:

```
df.d1 = df.d1.astype(np.float64) 
# do the same for d2..etc..
```

Comment: i edited my original post and quoted the statement which calculates the d values, didn't the 100.0 enforce float value? i even deliberately enclose it with float(), but the output is still missing those columns

Comment: @timeislove what are the dypes of columns d1..d10? you can check using df.dtypes if it doesn't say float64 and says object then it's likely that is it a float but I agree that it should have inferred this from your code but your output looks funny to me

Comment: you are right. it is about the type. i set dtype=np.float in df constructor of stock_analysis, and it works... what i dunno is, if i used the default=None for the stock_analysis construction, and set the elements by .loc, the dtype would not auto convert to the type i fill in, like enforcing with float(), but still consider the elements as 'object'!!! weird.

Comment: @timeislove yes it is odd, I don't know enough to explain this behaviour but glad I helped.